# Toast is showing after clicking the button two times

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, toast

I am creating android app using eclipce  , I used a click listener for a button to show a toast .Every thing is working ok but the problem that I need to click two times in the button to show the toast .Is there any way to force one clicking to show the toast?
This is the code that use

```
 public void showAnswer(View view) {

        Button b;
        b= findViewById(R.id.ans);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(),"Ø§Ù„Ù�ÙŠÙ„",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the XML layout that holds the button? It could be other views taking the first focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It costs you 2 taps because with the first one, you define your listener and the second one, your listener is called.

You have to define your `ClickListener` only one time. Generally, it's done in the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use only this if you are assigning  `showAnswer(View view)` to your `button` `onclick` event:

```
public void showAnswer(View view) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(),"Ø§Ù„Ù�ÙŠÙ„",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```